# Date format Excel

Tags: excel, date, format

I have a table that looks like this:

```
7/9/18 9:28 AM
7/9/18 10:28 AM
7/9/18 10:40 AM
7/9/18 10:43 AM
7/9/18 11:07 AM
```

I want it to look like this:

```
7/9/18 9:28 AM    First record
7/9/18 10:28 AM   Second record
7/9/18 10:40 AM   Third record
7/9/18 10:43 AM   Fourth record
7/9/18 11:07 AM   Fifth record
```

Can you help me? I tried searching Google, but I didn't find anything that could solve my problem.

Thanks.

Comment: How about `Record 1`, `Record 2`, ...  It would be easier.

Comment: It will be awesome like that too. Can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use COUNTIF:

```
="Record " & COUNTIF(A:A,"<=" &A1)
```

[image]